# FD_CLOSE Event Handler C++

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I want to register my socket to FD_CLOSE event.
I use

```
WSAEVENT NewEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSAEventSelect(_socket, NewEvent, FD_CLOSE)
```

my question is how do I handle the event when it will come? what function I need to add that I will know that the CLOSE happened?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the event using [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then determine which event occured using [`WSAEnumNetworkEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741572%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This also resets the event to an un-signaled state.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function? There's even an example in the linked manual page.